# Belated forward?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I said:

**It seems I missed saying Happy birthday to you! Belated accepted?**

to someone, and she replied:

**Thanks! Belated forward**.

What does **Belated forward** mean?

Comment: Your question needs more context.

Comment: I added all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the woman is making a joke with *word play*.

The only thing I can think of is

You have wished Happy Birthday late, asking

> Belated accepted?

meaning "Do you accept my belated wishes?"

She is using

> belated = late, behind
>   forward = early, in front

She then returns a "Thank you" to you

> belated forward

which may mean

> belated + forward = late + early = on time

where *belated* and *forward* cancel each other out, which obviously her "Thank you" is not *late*.